# How to change the size of layer with all elements in PHOTOSHOP?

Tags: height, width, scale, photoshop

I need the sizes of layer like width - 7sm, height - 10sm. Also all elements scaled correctly by size of layer the same time. Is it possible?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84gnI.jpg)

Comment: You might get a better response from [graphic design stack exchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To change the size of a project. Go to the image tab and select image size. To scale multiple layers at once. Click one and hold shift, then click another.